# How can I change protobuf logging behavior (separator)?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I use ShortDebugString() on protobuf message to get a string and log it to file. This function returns concise version with ':' as a separator. From protobuf code it looks like it happens in TextFormat::Printer::PrintField.

```
generator.Print(": ");
// Write the field value.
PrintFieldValue(message, reflection, field, field_index, generator);
```

I would like to change ':' to '=' in string returned from ShortDebugString. How can I accomplish this without changing protobuf library code itself? I can replace ':' with '=' after I get string back from ShortDebugString but I was hoping to avoid that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Really. You quote the code that shows `:` being hardcoded, and you ask how you can change it without changing it?

Comment: The output is meant to be in the "text format" which can be parsed with the corresponding input parser. If you changed the output, it would lose this property.

Comment: Sehe, you read it right. Perhaps there is a way to override PrintField or provide custom Printer for scalar types. So I am looking for something perhaps in that direction.

Comment: kerrek, that's a great point. I was only hopping to change this so that log becomes more appropriate for Splunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here is to copy the whole `TextFormat` class and modify it. The `TextFormat` code does not use any private protobuf APIs, so you should have no problem moving it out of the core library. In fact, `TextFormat` was designed in part to serve as an example for how you might write your own encoders for alternate textual formats, which it sounds like is exactly what you want here. :)

Comment: Just to be clear, you are recommending that I modify TextFormat class and compile protobuf from source to build new library (libprotobuf.so). Or perhaps you are suggesting that we keep same protobuf core library but write new library that only has TextFormat class with shortDebugString implementation that suites us. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user2903819: I am suggesting that you copy of text_format.cc and text_format.h into your own code (or perhaps a new library), change the namespace (and maybe rename the class), and then modify as needed. You should not modify the protobuf library itself; you're basically creating an entirely new class but using TextFormat as a template instead of starting from scratch.